# HSV to RGB color conversion via python

Tags: python, python-2.7, color-space

I'd like to convert my HSV color to an RGB color.
Set the HSV values to 213, 18% and 98%:

```
import colorsys
color1 = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(213, 0.18, 0.98)
```

The result is:

```
(249.9, 204.91800000000003, 204.91800000000003)
```

Although it should be: (208, 225, 250)

What am I missing?

Comment: Where did you get your values from?

Comment: You just need to correctly map your values to the range [0,1]. E.g. 213 -> 213.0/360.0 (360 comes from HSV-definition). The docs of colorsys mentions, that it just accept floats within this range. I'm not that familiar with these calculations and rounding-rules, but mapping this, gives me ```[205.72160000000002, 226.04288, 250.88]``` which is quite near your desired result.